# Value of optional type 'PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?' must be unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, applepay, xcode10.2

When I try to compile react-native app for iOS below code block for ApplePay

```
    let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
    applePayController.delegate = self
    let rootViewController:UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController!
    rootViewController!.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

throwing run-time error.

`Value of optional type 'PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'delegate' of wrapped base type 'PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController'`

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` has a *failable initialiser* - that is, the initialiser will return `nil` if the user is unable to make payments.

This means that `applePayController` is an *optional* - it may contain `nil`, so just as the error says you need to unwrap the optional before you can access the property; `applePayController?.delegate = self`.  A better approach is to use an `if let` or `guard let`.

For example:

```
if let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request), 
   let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
    applePayController.delegate = self
    rootViewController.present(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    // Payment is unavailable - handle this as appropriate
}
```

There is no need to specify the type when Swift can infer it.  It is also best to avoid force unwrapping optionals.